# deleting li:first animating rest of list upwards changing opacity at same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

After reading up on jq my problem still is here.
I'll rephrase the question .. maybe i'll get more response ;)

I'm trying to run 2 animations at the same time on different elements in a UL

deleting the first line, animating the rest up and changing opacity at the same time.

so far i got this :

```
$('#NextUp li:first').slideUp( 500 , function() { 
    $('#NextUp li:first').remove();
    $('#NextUp li:first').attr('id', 'regel1');
});
$( ".t > li" ).each(function( intIndex ){
    var i =  1 - ($('li').index ($(this))/5) ;
    $(this).next().animate({ opacity: i }, {duration: 500,  queue: false})
});
```

resulting in 2 animations following one another.

i tried to change the slideup to use animate instead, but it doesnt want to complete. (i.e. the animation is stopped before completion line does not get deleted)

how can i run these 2 animations at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
function fadeaway(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el.animate({'height' : 0}, 1000,
                   function(){
                       $(this).remove();
                       fadeaway($('ul.next_up > li:first'));
                   });                            
    }
}

fadeaway($('ul.next_up > li:first'));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9LFjx/).

This animates the height of the passed in element to zero, removes that element in the callback and then calls the function again to act upon the next element.

---

Revised the above code:

```
function fadeaway(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el.delay(500).animate({'height' : 0}, 1000,
                   function(){
                       var next = $(this).next();
                       $(this).remove();
                       fadeaway(next);
                   });                            
    }
}

fadeaway($('ul.next_up > li:first'));​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9LFjx/).

This does much the same as the above, but offers a delay (of 500 milliseconds) between animations, and allows the function to work out what the next sibling should be, rather than explicitly hard-coding it.

Also, in that approach, it gives a moment for the CSS-transitions to catch up...

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: not really what i was looking for (probably caused by the way i formulated the question haha), but has got enough clues for me to figure it out :)
thanks for your answer!